# Updating Location and ShipQty in Acumatica Shipment Lines

Tags: web-services, acumatica

I'm having this weird problem in acumatica webservices, I'm updating existing Shipments in acumatica using webservices. My code is supposed to update the Location and ShippedQty but for no reason it updates all the items except the last one. It happens when the Shipment has multiple items. Please help me solve this problem, below is my code and an image of the Shipment screen with the last item not updated.

Thanks.

```
var commands = new List<Acumatica_LSOne_Integration.SO302000.Command>();
        commands.Add(new SO302000.Value { Value = shipmentNbr, LinkedCommand = shipmentSchema.ShipmentSummary.ShipmentNbr });
        commands.Add(new SO302000.Value { Value = shipmentType, LinkedCommand = shipmentSchema.ShipmentSummary.Type });
        commands.Add(shipmentSchema.DocumentDetails.ShipmentNbr);
        commands.Add(shipmentSchema.DocumentDetails.LineNbr);
        commands.Add(shipmentSchema.DocumentDetails.InventoryID);
        commands.Add(shipmentSchema.DocumentDetails.Warehouse);
        commands.Add(shipmentSchema.DocumentDetails.Location);
        commands.Add(shipmentSchema.DocumentDetails.OrderedQty);
        var soLines = context.Submit(commands.ToArray());

        List<Acumatica_LSOne_Integration.SO302000.Command> commandList = new List<Acumatica_LSOne_Integration.SO302000.Command>();
        for (int index = 0; index < soLines.Length; index++)
        {
            string sShipNbr = soLines[index].DocumentDetails.ShipmentNbr.Value;
            string sLineNbr = soLines[index].DocumentDetails.LineNbr.Value;
            string sInventoryID = soLines[index].DocumentDetails.InventoryID.Value;
            string sWarehouse = soLines[index].DocumentDetails.Warehouse.Value;
            string sLocation = soLines[index].DocumentDetails.Location.Value;
            string sOrderedQty = soLines[index].DocumentDetails.OrderedQty.Value;

            commandList.Add(new SO302000.Key
            {
                ObjectName = shipmentSchema.DocumentDetails.ShipmentNbr.ObjectName,
                FieldName = shipmentSchema.DocumentDetails.ShipmentNbr.FieldName,
                Value = sShipNbr.Trim(), Commit = true                    
            });

            commandList.Add(new SO302000.Key
            {
                ObjectName = shipmentSchema.DocumentDetails.LineNbr.ObjectName,
                FieldName = shipmentSchema.DocumentDetails.LineNbr.FieldName,
                Value = sLineNbr.Trim(), Commit = true                    
            });
            commandList.Add(new SO302000.Value
            {
                Value = vLocation.Trim(),
                LinkedCommand = shipmentSchema.DocumentDetails.Location
            });
            commandList.Add(new SO302000.Value { Value = sOrderedQty, LinkedCommand = shipmentSchema.DocumentDetails.ShippedQty,IgnoreError = true, Commit = true });

        }

        commandList.Add(shipmentSchema.Actions.ConfirmShipmentAction);
        context.Submit(commandList.ToArray());
```

Sample Output:
[image]

Comment: May be its a silly question but did you try to debug the code and made sure that your loop sets all values as expected?

Comment: tried that already and it loops and sets value well....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've actually come up with a solution that works well using the Contract Based Web Services. Below is my sample code:

```
using (DefaultSoapClient soapClient = new DefaultSoapClient())
                    {
                        InitializeWebService(soapClient,sAUser,sAPass,vCompany,vBranchID);

                        Shipment shipmentToBeFound = new Shipment
                        {
                            Type = new StringSearch { Value = shipmentType },
                            ShipmentNbr = new StringSearch { Value = shipmentNbr },
                        };
                        Shipment shipment = (Shipment)soapClient.Get(shipmentToBeFound);

                        int iLineNbr =  Int32.Parse(sLineNbr);
                        ShipmentDetail shipmentLine = shipment.Details.Single(
                            orderLineToBeUpdated =>                                
                            orderLineToBeUpdated.LineNbr.Value == iLineNbr);
                            shipmentLine.LocationID = new StringValue { Value = vLocation.Trim() };
                            shipmentLine.ShippedQty = new DecimalValue { Value = decimal.Parse(sOrderedQty) };

                            shipment = (Shipment)soapClient.Put(shipment);

                        soapClient.Logout();

                    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I guessed that you have allowed negative quantity on your inventory, by default when an item has zero quantity on a particular warehouse the location will set as  and a shipped quantity of zero and as  I've seen you're code, check this line code

> string sLocation = soLines[index].DocumentDetails.Location.Value;

if this soLine retreives a value as I guess this line is the cause why it won't update.

Comment: i dont think so, im using another Location variable to update the field which is vLocation. `commandList.Add(new SO302000.Value
            {
                Value = vLocation.Trim(),
                LinkedCommand = shipmentSchema.DocumentDetails.Location
            });`